# Static timestamp for multiple columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having quite a headache trying to get this to work. I want a script for my Google sheet that will give me a static timestamp based on specific values for multiple columns. I've used the script below:

```
//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 9;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,13];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'Pipeline'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

This works great for a single column, but it doesn't work when I try to duplicate the script for other columns. I've tried to make an array without success either. Keep in mind I'm no expert with this stuff.

For context: There are six different stages of progress that I track in columns 9-14, and I track them using four different values. I want to get a timestamp for each time I change from one value to the next, so that I can track the time each stage takes. I'm new to this, thanks for your patience.

[Image of spreadsheet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb4XN.png)

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Please provide images with explanation

Comment: @Cooper Added a photo of the spreadsheet. I want an automatic, static timestamp for columns 9-14 as they change from one stage to another.

Comment: Where do the timestamps go for column 9

Comment: Ultimately I want them in column 23 (W). I was trying a workaround where the timestamp went instead to column 22, and then were pulled by an if function to column 23 depending on the stage. However the script I posted did not seem to work for multiple columns: 10, 11, 12, etc.

Comment: I don't understand the value of putting them all in the same cell.  How will you know what they mean.  I think I'm missing something in you explanation perhaps you could provide an image with the timestamps shown for each column that changes

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was exactly what I needed. Once the timestamp is put in, I use an if function that filters out the timestamp based the stage it's in, and keeps it that way. It should work smoothly from here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const cols = [9,10,11,12,13];
  const idx = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  if(sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && ~idx){
    e.range.offset(0,6).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```